# OutputStreamWriter encoding vs response content-type

Tags: java, web, character-encoding, http-headers, outputstream

I have an `OutputStreamWriter` in my Servlet that uses a particular encoding scheme, i.e. I have to use this constructor

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
```

Also, I have used the following line of code to set the encoding scheme of the response

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")
```

Using this output stream I am sending response to the client.

Now in the browser the decoding will be done by which scheme UTF-8 or charsetName.
Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
```

tells the writer which charset to use for encoding.

The line

```
 response.setContentType(text/html;charset=UTF-8)
```

sets the `contentType` header in the `http` response and tells the browser which encoding to use for displaying the content.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will handle the content based on the `Content-Type` header. The charset you use for the `OutputStreamWriter` only affects how characters written to it are encoded into bytes.